# vegetation types and their required or suitable climate condition

Tags: climate, climate-change, vegetation

I am doing a variability analysis for landcover in Western Ghats region.
I have various vegetation classes such as:

- evergreen (needle leaf, broad leaf),
- decidious (needle leaf, broad leaf),
- shrubland (open, closed),
- savannah,
- woody savannah,
- grassland,
- mixed forest,
- cropland,
- etc.

I want to know the suitable temperature and rainfall conditions that these vegetation types need to thrive or survive.

Comment: You really need much more finely categorized vegetation classes to determine optimal growing conditions.  These categories are too broad to give anything worthwhile.  These sound like landcover categories from satellite retrieval, which has different responses depending on the region.  I would be hesitant to put too much confidence in these land types for a region the satellite algorithm wasn't developed for.  Perhaps you could provide a list of the types of species that would be expected within these categories.

Comment: Thank you , but there has got to be a climate zone or particular broad weather parameter for the vegetation types to thrive all over the world . I just need a broad idea about the climate condition.